# what is configuration needed to set up for asp .net core web component scaling?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

//Startup.cs

We added configuration for openid connect -- Azure AD(authorization), the below code is working if only one instance is running. If we scaled as 3 instances, then instances are running as expected (dockerized containers), but the authorization is not happening?

```
        services.AddAuthentication(
           options =>
           {
               options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           }).AddCookie(options => new CookieAuthenticationOptions
           {
               LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/"),
               ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
               SlidingExpiration = false,
           }).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
               options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
               options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
               options.Authority = Configuration["AADInstance"] + Configuration["TenantId"];
               options.CallbackPath = Configuration["CallbackPath"];
               options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
           });
```

I got the below error in one of the instances

```
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[14]
  .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[14]
  .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  A unhandled exception has occurred: Correlation failed.
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.    <HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() atSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Comment: Ever resolved this? Mind sharing your fix? Thanks.